# custom circular view. placing of views

Tags: android, android-layout, geometry

Yesterday i tried to create a custom view where all the elements
like buttons, imagebuttons, ... are placed around a circle with 
equal spacing.

My goal was to get this:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
public class CircleView extends RelativeLayout {
    private OnDrop onDrop = null;
    private int radius = -1;
    private double step = -1;
    private double angle = -1;
    private static final int CENTER_ID = 111;

    public CircleView(Context context, OnDrop onDrop, int radius, List<View> elements) {
        super(context);

        this.onDrop = onDrop;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.step = (2 * Math.PI) / elements.size();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsView = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsView);
        this.addView(this.createCenter(context));

        for(View view : elements) {
            this.addView(this.placeView(view));
        }
    }

    private View placeView(View view) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = createNewRelativeLayoutParams();

        int x = (int)(view.getWidth() / 2 + this.radius * Math.cos(this.angle));
        int y = (int)(view.getHeight() / 2 + this.radius * Math.sin(this.angle));

        this.angle += this.step;

        layoutParams.setMargins(x, 0, 0, y);
        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return view;
    }

    private View createCenter(Context context) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Globals.DRAG_TARGET_SIZE, Globals.DRAG_TARGET_SIZE);
        layoutParams.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layoutParams.addRule(CENTER_VERTICAL);

        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setId(CENTER_ID);
        button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        return button;
    }

    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams createNewRelativeLayoutParams() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParameters.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParameters.addRule(RIGHT_OF, CENTER_ID);

        return layoutParameters;
    }
}
```

What i got from this code is this:

[image]

That means the creation of the circle with equal spacing between 
the elements is working quite good. But there is still a problem
with the placing. Something is wrong with the x and y coordinate.

Can someone help me figuring out how to correct this offset?

Comment: extent ViewGroup,  not RelativeLayout

Comment: why? does that solve my problem?

Comment: speciailized / custom layouts should extend VG since it is more natural approach

Comment: i just got it working with relativeLayout. maybe when there is time later i will take a look at ViewGroup. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented my own Layout to place buttons circulary around a center point:

```
/**
 *
 */
public class MenuCircularLayout extends MenuDragableButtonsLayout {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutCenter = null;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private List<View> menuButtons = null;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private ImageButton imageButtonCenter = null;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private int radius = -1;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private double step = -1;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private double angle = -1;
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final int CENTER_ID = View.generateViewId();

    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param callbackDrag
     * @param menuButtons
     */
    public MenuCircularLayout(Context context, CallbackDrag callbackDrag, List<View> menuButtons) {
        super(context);

        this.callbackDrag = callbackDrag;
        this.menuButtons = menuButtons;
        this.radius = Sizes.getDpToPx(context, Sizes.MENU_ICON_RADIUS);
        this.step = (2 * Math.PI) / menuButtons.size();

        this.initView();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void initView() {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Sizes.getOptimalMenuHeight(this.getContext()));
        layoutParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        this.relativeLayoutCenter = new RelativeLayout(this.getContext());
        this.relativeLayoutCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsCenter);
        this.relativeLayoutCenter.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsImageButtonCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParamsImageButtonCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        this.imageButtonCenter = new ImageButton(this.getContext());
        this.imageButtonCenter.setId(CENTER_ID);
        this.imageButtonCenter.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsImageButtonCenter);
        this.imageButtonCenter.setImageDrawable(Images.loadDrawableFromFile(this.getContext(), Paths.IMAGE_POWER));
        this.imageButtonCenter.setBackground(null);
        this.imageButtonCenter.setOnDragListener(new DropTargetOnDragListener());
        this.imageButtonCenter.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);

        this.relativeLayoutCenter.addView(imageViewCenter);
        this.relativeLayoutCenter.addView(this.imageButtonCenter);
        this.relativeLayoutCenter.setOnDragListener(new MenuButtonOnDragListener());

        for(View view : this.menuButtons) {
            this.relativeLayoutCenter.addView(this.placeView(view));
        }

        this.addView(this.relativeLayoutCenter);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param view
     * @return
     */
    private View placeView(View view) {
        view.measure(0, 0);

        this.imageButtonCenter.measure(0, 0);

        int x = (int)((view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2) + this.radius * Math.cos(this.angle));
        int y = (int)((view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2) + this.radius * Math.sin(this.angle));

        this.angle += this.step;

        int deltaX = view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int deltaY = view.getMeasuredHeight();
        int deltaImageX = this.imageButtonCenter.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int deltaImageY = this.imageButtonCenter.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        int xToDraw = ((x - deltaX) - deltaImageX);
        int yToDraw = ((y - deltaY) - deltaImageY);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, CENTER_ID);
        layoutParams.setMargins(xToDraw, 0, 0, yToDraw);

        view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public void removeAllViews() {
        super.removeAllViews();

        this.relativeLayoutCenter.removeAllViews();
    }
}


/**
 * 
 */
public abstract class MenuDragableButtonsLayout extends RelativeLayout implements OnTouchListener {
    /**
     * 
     */
    protected CallbackDrag callbackDrag = null;

    /**
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public MenuDragableButtonsLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            view.performClick();
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public class MenuButtonOnDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
            View sourceView = (View) event.getLocalState();

            float sourceX = sourceView.getX();
            float sourceY = sourceView.getY();
            float dropX = event.getX() - (sourceView.getWidth() / 2);
            float dropY = event.getY() - (sourceView.getHeight() / 2);

            switch(event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED : {
                    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(dropX - sourceX, 0, dropY - sourceY, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(300);

                    sourceView.startAnimation(animation);
                    sourceView.setX(sourceX);
                    sourceView.setY(sourceY);
                    sourceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP : {
                    sourceView.setX(dropX);
                    sourceView.setY(dropY);
                    sourceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(dropX - sourceX, 0, dropY - sourceY, 0);
                    animation.setDuration(300);

                    sourceView.startAnimation(animation);
                    sourceView.setX(sourceX);
                    sourceView.setY(sourceY);
                } break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public class DropTargetOnDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        /**
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP :
                return callbackDrag.onDragCompleted(view, event);
            default :
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * 
 */
public interface CallbackDrag {
    /**
     * 
     * @param view
     * @param event
     * @return
     */
    boolean onDragCompleted(final View view, final DragEvent event);
}
```

Use it like:

```
public class AnyClass implements CallbackDrag {

    private MenuCircularLayout circleView = null;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private void initMenu() {
        String email = this.getEmail();
        Map<String, Boolean> config = this.preferencesSettings.getSettings(email);

        List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
        views.add(this.buttonProfile);
        views.add(this.buttonMeasure);

        if(this.circleView != null) {
            this.circleView.removeAllViews();
            this.layoutMenu.removeView(this.circleView);

            this.circleView = null;
        }

        this.circleView = new MenuCircularLayout(this.getActivity(), this, views);
        this.circleView.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
        this.layoutMenu.addView(this.circleView);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onDragCompleted(View view, DragEvent event) {
        View sourceView = (View) event.getLocalState();

        sourceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(sourceView.equals(this.buttonMeasure)) {
            this.performNFCResult();
        } else if(sourceView.equals(this.buttonProfile)) {
            this.performProfile();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Muigard, Can u please provide more info about this answer like "OnDrop" Class, Globals.DRAG_TARGET_SIZE, Globals.DRAG_TARGET_SIZE and so on and mainly how can we use this class. Pls Help!!

Comment: I posted my full code. There is much room for improvement but it is working very well. The constants like the sizes and radius and so on you can set as you wish.