# how to release memory occupied by bitmaps

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am creating an app which shows imageviews in a circular manner. It shows the icons of settings e.g, Bluetooth, wifi, etc. There's no out of memory error, but after finishing the activity, the app still uses approx. 15mb RAM on Bitmaps according to Memory Analyzer Tool. How, can I release those bitmaps.

Here's the code for creating the circular view :

```
    settingsImageViews = new ArrayList<View>(0);

    // create settings icon views
    for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        if (i > 2 && i != 10) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getSettingsIcon(i - 3));
        } else if (i == 10) {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_key));
        } else {
            imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }

        settingsImageViews.add(imageView);
    }

    settingsCircularView = new CircleView(this, CIRCLE_RADIUS, settingsImageViews);
    parentLayout.addView(settingsCircularView);
```

For circular view I'm using this code : [custom circular view. placing of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818748/custom-circular-view-placing-of-views?rq=1)

`getSettingsIcon` method :

```
private Drawable getSettingsIcon(int settingId) {
    switch (settingId) {

    case 0:// bluetooth
        if (PhoneSetting.isBluetoothOn())
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth);
        else
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth_off);

    case 1:// wifi
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wifi_on);
        else
            return getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wifi_off);
    .
    .
    .
    }
}
```

I tried to recycle the bitmaps in `onDestroy` method, but when I reopen the activity it crashes because of the `trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap` error.

I even tried to call `System.gc()`, but the app still uses 15mb RAM.

I'm also destroying all the views in `onDestroy` using `unbindDrawables` method :

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {       
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
                view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                        unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
                }
                ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        }
}
```

After trying all of the above things not even 1 mb got reduced. The resources also use approx. 4.5 mb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you having OOM problems?

Since you are using `getDrawable(R.drawable.superAwesomeFractal)` Android is maintaining a cache of the bitmaps--for instance, if you set the same drawable on two different `ImageView`s Android is not allocating twice the space. Which is to say, since you are not explicitly creating/decoding/using bitmaps, unless you are seeing actual problems such as OOM exception, you don't need to worry releasing them or recycling their allocations--Android will handle that for you. Which is incidentally why you are getting the exception about trying to reuse a recycled bitmap.

Comment: Ok, so I can't release that memory? But, can I reduce the memory it consumes? If yes, How?

Comment: Tailor the bitmaps by making sure you are using optimal encoding (ie, if you don't need alpha, don't use a format with alpha). Replace pngs with xml created drawables where possible (like gradient backgrounds). There's not much else you can do: but again, don't worry about the memory footprint if it is not causing you problems and is not off the charts (15mb is not particularly if you are displaying lots of images).